# Could you please help me to understand logic using for loop on dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like below;

```
groups.head()

   reconstruction_error    true_class
183484   0.290310            0
255448   0.225183            0
244749   1.047568            0
63919    0.541144            0
11475    0.694220            0
83053    3.471817            1
221041   5.833817            1 
6717     13.987760           1
263080   0.809129            1
231978   4.028153            1
```

Below code is plotting index versus reconsturction error and changing marker color if true_class is  0 or 1.  I really dont understand how indicator 'name' matching true_class columns? Maybe it represents reconsturction_error? And also same for indicator 'group'. Could you please explain structure here?

[Graphic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oktAR.png)

```
threshold = 6.0

groups = error_df.groupby('true_class')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.index, group.reconstruction_error, marker='o', ms=2.0, linestyle='',
            label = "Fraud" if name == 1 else "Normal",
            color = "red" if name == 1 else "blue")
ax.hlines(threshold, ax.get_xlim()[0], ax.get_xlim()[1], colors="green", zorder=100, label='Threshold')
ax.legend()
plt.title("Reconstruction error for different classes")
plt.ylabel("Reconstruction error")
plt.xlabel("Data point index")
plt.show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you performed grouping on *true_class*:

```
groups = error_df.groupby('true_class')
```

Then, to see how does your loop work, run:

```
for name, group in groups:
    print(name)
    print(group)
```

The result is:

```
0
        reconstruction_error  true_class
183484              0.290310           0
255448              0.225183           0
244749              1.047568           0
63919               0.541144           0
11475               0.694220           0
1
        reconstruction_error  true_class
83053               3.471817           1
221041              5.833817           1
6717               13.987760           1
263080              0.809129           1
231978              4.028153           1
```

You can see that *true_class* is saved just as *name*, because *for ... in groups:*
retrieves **tuples** containing of the grouping key and the group itself.

So your loop performs actually **2** plots:

- one for group with grouping key (*name*) == *0*,
- and the second for group with grouping key (*name*) == *1*.

In each case:

- *label* is set to *Normal* or *Fraud*,
- *color* is set to *blue* or *red*.